# Is there a way to write this Excel Formula in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Is there a way to write this Excel Formula in VBA?

```
=SUM(
 NUMBERVALUE(COUNTIF(SheetName!A:B,CONCATENATE((E3+1),(F3+1),G3,H3,I3,J3,$L$2))),
 NUMBERVALUE((COUNTIF(SheetName!A:B,CONCATENATE((E3+1),F3,G3,H3,I3,J3,$L$2))))+
 NUMBERVALUE((COUNTIF(SheetName!A:B,CONCATENATE((E3+1),(F3-1),G3,H3,I3,J3,$L$2))))+
 NUMBERVALUE((COUNTIF(SheetName!A:B,CONCATENATE(E3,(F3+1),G3,H3,I3,J3,$L$2))))+
 NUMBERVALUE((COUNTIF(SheetName!A:B,CONCATENATE(E3,F3,G3,H3,I3,J3,$L$2))))+
 NUMBERVALUE((COUNTIF(SheetName!A:B,CONCATENATE(E3,(F3-1),G3,H3,I3,J3,$L$2))))+
 NUMBERVALUE((COUNTIF(SheetName!A:B,CONCATENATE((E3-1),(F3+1),G3,H3,I3,J3,$L$2))))+
 NUMBERVALUE((COUNTIF(SheetName!A:B,CONCATENATE((E3-1),F3,G3,H3,I3,J3,$L$2))))+
 NUMBERVALUE((COUNTIF(SheetName!A:B,CONCATENATE((E3-1),(F3-1),G3,H3,I3,J3,$L$2)))))
```

please, is there a way I can write this formular in Excel VBA?

It concatenates cell values.  e.g
`X=cella1,    X=cellb1    X=cellc1 + etc...`  and gives all possible combinations of these values `X` as `Strings`
The **`Countif`**`function` goes to a different excel sheet in that workbook, and selects a `range` and then *counts* the cells in that range, that meets the `Strings` condition, which is given to it as its second argument.

`NumberValue` then converts the strings to `Integers`.
Lastly it takes the sum of these `Integers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, please:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 Set sh2 = Worksheets("SheetName") 'use here your real worksheet name
 'Adapt here the cell where to formula to be dropped:
 sh.Range("L3:L945").formula = "=SUM(NUMBERVALUE(COUNTIF(" & sh2.Name & "!A:B,CONCATENATE((E3+1)," & _
    "(F3+1),G3,H3,I3,J3,$L$2))),NUMBERVALUE((COUNTIF(" & sh2.Name & "!A:B,CONCATENATE((E3+1)," & _
    "F3,G3,H3,I3,J3,$L$2))))+NUMBERVALUE((COUNTIF(" & sh2.Name & "!A:B,CONCATENATE((E3+1),(F3-1)," & _
    "G3,H3,I3,J3,$L$2))))+NUMBERVALUE((COUNTIF(" & sh2.Name & "!A:B,CONCATENATE(E3,(F3+1),G3,H3," & _
    "I3,J3,$L$2))))+NUMBERVALUE((COUNTIF(" & sh2.Name & "!A:B,CONCATENATE(E3,F3,G3,H3,I3,J3,$L$2))))" & _
    "+NUMBERVALUE((COUNTIF(" & sh2.Name & "!A:B,CONCATENATE(E3,(F3-1),G3,H3,I3,J3,$L$2))))+NUMBERVALUE" & _
    "((COUNTIF(" & sh2.Name & "!A:B,CONCATENATE((E3-1),(F3+1),G3,H3,I3,J3,$L$2))))+NUMBERVALUE" & _
    "((COUNTIF(" & sh2.Name & "!A:B,CONCATENATE((E3-1),F3,G3,H3,I3,J3,$L$2))))+NUMBERVALUE" & _
    "((COUNTIF(" & sh2.Name & "!A:B,CONCATENATE((E3-1),(F3-1),G3,H3,I3,J3,$L$2)))))"
```

Comment: thank you very much ```@FaneDuru```.  please can I make the formula, populate on 400 rows automatically while the cell reference changes relatively?

Comment: @Pachino: In principle, yes. But it depends on what is to be incremented. Can you post the specific range to be populated with incremented formulas? I will adapt the code in a way to do that... It can be done at once for all the range. I mean, without iteration.

Comment: @Pachino: Still alive? I will leave home in some minutes and if you want solving your problem now, it would be good for you to be a little more responsive...

Comment: please I'm trying to type in the code..I'm almost done, give me few minutes. @FaneDuru

Comment: @Pachino: But it would be only a matter of writing here the range where you want the formula to be applied. Am I missing something?

Comment: I want it to be applied on L3:L945, while the references of the cell changes in relative, that is when it is being applied on L21, it uses the cell reference on E21, F21, .... to concatenate, I hope I explained it correctly, thanks.

Comment: @Pachino: Then, only the existing range must be changed with yours. I adapted the code. Please confirm that if does what you need. And, in such a case, we here vote the answer up and more important, we tick the left code side check box in order to make it **accepted answer**. When somebody else will search for a similar issue, he will understand that the code works...

Comment: I have to try it and get back to you, and that will take alot of time, but I'm sure it should work. thanks for now.

Comment: @Pachino:  Welcome! Glad I could help! If something unclear, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications...